# Last Tabs in User Data -- How do I open it into tabs on Chrome

Tags: tabbed-browsing

My Chrome browser crashed, but did not restore last session.

It found the last tabs open, but it's all in code, although I can see the URLs.

How do I open it in the browser itself, getting the tabs?

Chrome has some sort of buffer problem that all of a sudden makes it terribly slow and then crash, which I am unsure how to stop.

Comment: What happens when you hit CTRL+SHIFT+T?